# How to find the -index of an element of a list?

Tags: python, list, indexing

Having a list like `my_list`, I would like to find the -index of an element, meaning the place of the element counting from the end of the list.

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

For example, I want to find as a result that the -index of 'b' is `-2`.

Comment: `my_list.index('b') - len(my_list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] # len(my_list) = 4
negative_index = my_list.index('b') - len(my_list) # 1 - 4 = -3 

print(my_list[negative_index])
```

b

Answer (score 2):

Just another way...

```
>>> ~my_list[::-1].index('b')
-2
```

This also supports finding the last occurrence if there are several.

And if the list is long and the element is near the end, for example like `['z'] * 1000 + ['a', 'b', 'c']`, then it might be [faster](https://repl.it/repls/GregariousFilthyMatter#main.py) (18 μs vs 57 μs of the `index - len` solution). Even much faster (3.1 μs):

```
>>> (my_list.reverse(), ~my_list.index('b'), my_list.reverse())[1]
-2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is algebra, not even Python.

Write a short table of corresponding indices, say for a table of length 10:

```
+   -
0   -10
1   -9
2   -8
...
8   -2
9   -1
```

This is a simple linear relationship.  Derive the equation.  Finally, replace the constant `10` with `len(my_list)`.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: I am sorry can you give me a little bit more information?

Comment: Phht!  Thanks @superbrain!  Too much smoke inhalation today.  Fixed now, I think.

Comment: @ReaKalampaliki: You'll need to be specific about what information you need.  Stack Overflow doesn't work well with open-ended questions.

Comment: It was the table that confused me.. after the changes, i get to understand the mathematical calculus. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

An example of OP is ill-defined because `-index` can have any of these meanings:

- A number of steps needed to reach the first (leftmost) item of array if stepping backwards.
- A number of steps needed until first (righmost) item of array is met.

It's okay to have `my_list.index('b')` subtracted from `len(my_list)` and then inverse a sign of result in first case.

In second case we are flipping a list and applying `index` method on it so `-(list(reversed(my_list)).index('b) + 1)` or `-(my_list[::-1].index('b') + 1)` makes it. A second way is used more often.

Comment: Yes but it's still ill-defined (inverse of [well-defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-defined)). This is a contra-example where these interpretations gives different results: `my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c']`